# Sorting Table with JSON key with a space

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement a sort functionality on a table.

I am able to sort table headers with json(no spaces). However, I am unable to sort table headers with JSON key with spaces

How to solve this problem?

Script:
 $scope.sortType = 'Age'; 
    $scope.sortReverse = false;

HTML:

```
    <table border="1" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = x[First Name]">First Name
                                <span ng-show="sortType == x[First Name] && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                <span ng-show="sortType == x[First Name] && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                                </a>
                            </th>

 <th>
                            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = x[Last Name;sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                                Last Name
                                <span ng-show="sortType == x[Last Name]  && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                <span ng-show="sortType == x[Last Name] && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                            </a>
                        </th>


                            <th>
                                <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Age';sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                                    Age
                                    <span ng-show="sortType == 'Age' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                    <span ng-show="sortType == 'Age' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                                </a>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Address';sortReverse = !sortReverse">Address
                                    <span ng-show="sortType == 'Address' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                    <span ng-show="sortType == 'Address' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                                </a>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="x in result | filter:searchText | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
                            <td>{{x['First Name']}}</td>
                            <td>{{x['Last Name']}}</td>

                            <td>{{x.Age}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.Address}}</td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in your code which you should be seeing in your browser console.

Example:

```
<th>
    <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = x[First Name]">First Name
       <span ng-show="sortType == x[First Name] && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
       <span ng-show="sortType == x[First Name] && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
    </a>
</th>
```

It seems like you should be using the string literal `'First Name'` and not `x[First Name]` which is a syntax error and an undefined variable.

Try changing the above to:

```
<th>
    <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'First Name'">First Name
       <span ng-show="sortType == 'First Name' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
       <span ng-show="sortType == 'First Name' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
    </a>
</th>
```

That should help with the syntactical issues which you should be seeing in  your browser console right now and may solve the issue altogether.

Comment: I am able to sort, but the data is not actually sorting @segFault